# Ruby google request fails

Tags: ruby

I'm creating a Google Dork tool that sends a URL encoded query to google.com and returns the results as an array of links.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'cgi'
require 'socket'

# define full path to library
cwd = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
lib = File.join(cwd, "lib")

# require project library files
Dir.new(lib).each do |x|
  next unless x[/\.rb$/]
  begin
    require File.join(lib, x)
  rescue
    raise LoadError, "Failed to load #{x}."
  end
end

# build the google dork
def query(ext, site, inurl, intitle, intext)
  query, values = "", []
  dorks = %w(ext site inurl intitle intext)

  values.push(ext, site, inurl, intitle, intext)

  j = 0
  values.each do |i|
    dork = dorks[j]

    if dork.match(/^in/)
      value = %Q("#{i}")
    else
      value = i
    end

    query += "#{dork}:#{value} " unless i.nil?
    j += 1
  end

  query
end

# sends the search query to google.com
def search(host, query, agent)
  sock, links = TCPSocket.new(host, 80), []
  query = CGI::escape(query).chop
  request = "GET /search?q=#{query} HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"# HTTP/1.0\r\nUser-Agent: #{agent}\r\nConnection: Close\r\n\r\n"

  sock.puts request
  response = sock.read
  body = response.split("\r\n\r\n", 2)[1]

  body.split("url?q=").each do |link|
    link = link.to_s.split("&amp;", 0)[0]

    links << link if link.match(/^http|^https/) and link !~ /^http:\/\/webcache/
  end

  links
end

agent = RandomAgent.new
host = "google.com"

q = query(ARGV[0], ARGV[1], ARGV[2], ARGV[3], ARGV[4])
puts search(host, q, agent.randomize)
```

For some reason that I have yet to figure out, if I send the request manually, it works. However, if I send it using my ruby script it returns a 302 error. For example:

> GET /search?q=ext%3Apdf+site%3Agithub.com+inurl%3A%22email%22 HTTP/1.0

This is the request generated by my script. However when using the script I get an HTTP 302 error. If I manually send the same request using nc then it returns results.

> nc google.com 80
>
> GET /search?q=ext%3Apdf+site%3Agithub.com+inurl%3A%22email%22 HTTP/1.0

On top of that, if I only send this:

> GET /search?q=ext%3Apdf+site%3Agithub.com HTTP/1.0

It works. The third parameter causes it to have issues for some reason. I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First off, a 302 is not an error, it is a redirecting you.

In this case the 302 is the result of Google redirecting you from `http://google.com` to `https://google.com`.

If you want to use sockets for this you'll need to deal with any redirects and the SSL handshake. Maybe checkout [Net::HTTP](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) which can handle all of that for you?